# Is there a way to calculate cpu usage in typescript app through the code?

Tags: angular, typescript, cpu, cpu-usage, ram

I need to calculate cpu usage in persentage and log it to file every 20 ms, and i wanted to know if there a way to do it?
Thanks for your answers

I saw that there are solutions in node

Answer (score 0):

There is no API in browser JS to allow for this.